# Disable hover function using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

http://jsfiddle.net/2CkKW/5/

I'm trying to have a button for comments in which you will press the first button, It will then change to the mouseover colour and show the "add comment" button. Then when the user clicks the comment button again it will go back to the "unhover" state and hide the "add comment" button.

Thanks for your help, Hope it's not to badly worded to understand.

Comment: You should copy your code off jsFiddle and post it here for posterity in the event it helps someone in the future and jsFiddle disappears off the face of the web.  Additionally, what's the actual difficulty you're having with your current code? It would help to identify what isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check `if(showing == 0)` condition inside the `hover` first handler. But instead of using a global variable you can check the visibility of the add comment button. Try this

```
$("#commentsempty").hover(
    function(){
        if(!$("#addcomment").is(':visible')){
          $(this).css("background-position", "-148px");
          $("#commentsstatus").css("color", "#35a4de");
        }
    },
    function(){
    $(this).css("background-position", "-185px");
    $("#commentsstatus").css("color", "#484848");
})

$("#commentsempty").click(function(){
    if(!$("#addcomment").is(':visible')){
        $("#addcomment").fadeIn(500);
        $(this).css("background-position", "-148px");
        $("#commentsstatus").css("color", "#35a4de");
    }else{
        $("#addcomment").fadeOut(500);
        $(this).css("background-position", "-185px");
        $("#commentsstatus").css("color", "#484848");
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CkKW/9/)**

Comment: I was able to make it work with your suggestion oh having if(showing == 0) on the inside. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3):

I have shortened your code a little :) Down to 4 lines:

```
$("#commentsempty").click(function() {
    $("#addcomment").toggle(500);
    $(this).toggleClass('over');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2CkKW/10/

My advice: make use of CSS where it's possible and where it can be done with CSS.